# PHP & JSON working on localhost but not on shared hosting

Tags: php, json, api

I have an API I’m trying to integrate into my web application (a bitcoin website), which is written in php. The API has a php library, and they communicate through JSON. On my server I have 3 scripts: the script that calls the function I require (blockTest.php), the script that has all my credentials (i.e. API key, pin, API version; cred.php), and the library for the block.io API which has all their methods (block_io.php).

My first php script has the following code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once 'block_io.php';
require_once 'cred.php';

$addressInfo = $block_io_btc->get_my_addresses(array())

?>
```

I’ve set up the development environment on my localhost and these scripts work fine. I can make all the calls to the block.io API and get the appropriate data. However, when I upload my scripts to my shared hosting i get the following errors:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Failed: '
in/home/sites/public_html/vendor/block_io.php:124 Stack trace: #0
/home/sites/public_html/vendor/block_io.php(65): BlockIo-
>_request('get_my_addresse...', Array) #1
/home/sites/public_html/vendor/blockTest.php(14): BlockIo-
>__call('get_my_addresse...', Array) #2 
/home/sites/public_html/vendor/blockTest.php(14): BlockIo-
>get_my_addresses(Array) #3 {main} thrown in 
/home/sites/public_html/vendor/block_io.php on line 124
```

Step by step, this corresponds to the following lines of code in block_io.php(65):

```
$response = $this->_request($name, $args);
```

and in blockTest.php(14):

```
$addressInfo = $block_io_btc->get_my_addresses(array())
```

and in block_io.php(124):

```
if ($json_result->status != 'success') { throw new Exception('Failed: ' .    
$json_result->data->error_message); }

   // Spit back the response object or fail
  return $result ? $json_result : false;        
}
```

The error is that status != success. This is the http status, but there is no data->error_message. I went onto their website to play around with their API. If I enter my details correctly I get the following output:

[status = 200:success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY9Yy.png)

As you can see the response is a 200: success with the correct credentials. When I change the credentials by entering the wrong API key I get the following:

[status = 404:error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvpX3.png)

In the latter case there is a 404: error. In my production environment I do not get any data->error_message. This lead me to believe that the php version my Web host uses might be creating the problem with json_decode(), since block_io.php line 121-130 is this:

```
$json_result = json_decode($result);

if ($json_result->status != 'success') { throw new Exception('Failed: ' .    
$json_result->data->error_message); }

   // Spit back the response object or fail
 return $result ? $json_result : false;        
}
```

I’ve made sure my php version on MAMP is the same as my web host (5.5). Still nothing (remember the exact same script works fine on localhost). I checked the http status of my script here and all is good:

(reputation isn't good enough to post more than 2 links, but my server is responding with a 200:success status)

So…. I really don’t know what the problem is. The phpinfo() for my web host shows that they have JSON enabled and as far as I can tell they do not have magic_quotes = on in their php.ini. If they did have magic_quotes on I attempted to stripslashes() on the $json_result & separately on $result in block_io.php but to no avail. Now I really don’t know what else to try!

Comment: Where are you getting the JSON from? Maybe your shared webhost is blocking calls like `file_get_contents()`. What does `phpinfo()` say about `allow_url_fopen`?

Comment: Is there any way to check that? I suppose the JSON is coming directly from the block.io API...

Comment: What does `phpinfo()` say about `allow_url_fopen`?

Comment: no matches when I ctr+f 'allow_url_fopen'

Comment: You could test that with `<?php echo ini_get('allow_url_fopen'); ?>`

Comment: echo ini_get('allow_url_fopen'); returns '1'. What does that tell me? The script still doesn't execute.

Comment: It tells us, that it's not blocked. Still seems like a configuration issue to me though but I can't really help you any further. You could try and place some `echo` or `print_r` calls in that block_io.php to track the state of the variables.

Comment: OK thanks for your help. I'm trying a bunch of var_dumps to see what I find